# How to Mask a WPF Infragistics NumericField from another field

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, masking

I have a field I need masked but the mask format can differ depending upon the actual record. The table contains specification records and each type of spec can have a different precision. I am unable to set this precision in Xaml code.

I have tried the following:

```
 <inf:NumericField Name="ResultQty" Label="Test Results" Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Mask="{Binding FormatDesc}"/>
```

and

```
<inf:NumericField Name="ResultQty" Label="Test Results" Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Format="{Binding FormatDesc}"/>
```

FormatDesc returns ###,##0.000 for this record and ResultQty is 0.2720. It should display as 0.272 but is displaying as 0.27.

Is there a way to bind the FormatDesc property to the field in the Xaml or should I be looking for a different approach?

Comment: Run application in debugger and look at the output log. Perhaps there are messages like
`System.Windows.Data Error: 2: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element...`?

Comment: So the output gives the following 

System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedIssue.ContractIssueSpecDev.FailingTestResults.FormatDesc; DataItem=null; target element is 'NumericField' (HashCode=53877781); target property is 'Format' (type 'String')

Answer (score 1):

[On the Infragistics site there is the following explanation for a similar problem:](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-wpf/118058/xamdatagrid-binding-field-width)

> Fields in the `XamDataGrid` are not visual elements in WPF, and as such
> cannot be bound directly to a data context, as they do not expose one
> inherited from `FrameworkElement`.
>
> In order to bind the properties of the non-visual elements of the
> `XamDataGrid` such as `Field`, `FieldSettings`, or `FieldLayoutSettings`, I
> would recommend using a `FieldBinding`. You can read about `FieldBinding`
> in the `XamDataGrid` here:
> [https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-binding-field-fieldlayout-to-mvvm.](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-binding-field-fieldlayout-to-mvvm)

So, on the Infragistics site is recommended to use `FieldBinding` markup extension in order to bind properties to the `Field`, `FieldSettings`, or `FieldLayoutSettings`.
While mentioned post includes example that uses the MVVM pattern the `FieldBinding` markup extension can be used without it.

**For example, suppose the following data model is used:**

```
public class TestReportProvider : ObservableModel
{
    public TestReportProvider()
    {         
    }

    public string QtyFormat { get; set; } = "###,##0.000";

    private ObservableCollection<Test> _tests = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests
    {
        get
        {
            return this._tests;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._tests != value)
            {
                this._tests = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Tests");
            }
        }
    }
    //… 
}
```

**Set the `DataContext` in code-behind:**

```
public partial class FieldBindingExample : Window
{
    public TestReportProvider ReportData = new TestReportProvider();
    public FieldBindingExample()
    {        
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = ReportData;
    }
    //…
}
```

**Now set `DataSource` for the `XamDataGrid` and use the `FieldBinding` markup extension:**

```
<Grid>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Path=Tests}" AutoFit="True">
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>            
            <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"
                                      AutoFitMode="Always" 
                                      AddNewRecordLocation="OnTopFixed"/>                   
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>

            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>    
                        <igDP:TextField Name="TestDescription" Label="Test Description" />
                        <igDP:NumericField Name="Result" Label="Result" />
                        <igDP:NumericField Name="Average" Label="Average Deviation" 
                                           Format="{igDP:FieldBinding QtyFormat}" />                            
                    </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>         
</Grid>
```