# WPF Binding to parent object in an XamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics, legacy-code, xamdatagrid

I have inherited a legacy project that uses WPF. We make use of Infragistics.

Below is a made-up class structure:

```
public class DogsVM
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; } = "My Dogs";
    public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public string DogName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a `XamDataGrid` to display my data.

Currently the DataSource on the `XamDataGrid` is `DataSource="{Binding CollectionView}"`.

When I output the field I am using the following

```
<igDP:Field Name="DogName " Label="Dog Name" AllowEdit="False" />
```

I want the change the Label to be from `DogsVM` and select the field `ViewName`

If I do

```
<igDP:Field Name="DogName " Label="{Binding ViewName}" AllowEdit="False" />
```

**DogName** is outputted as I am looking at a `Dog` object, not a `DogsVM` object. How can I get to the parent object in the label binding?

Comment: This is a simplified example. The label will be dynamically created and not a hard coded string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[On the Infragistics site there is the following explanation for a similar problem:](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-wpf/118058/xamdatagrid-binding-field-width)

> Fields in the `XamDataGrid` are not visual elements in WPF, and as such
> cannot be bound directly to a data context, as they do not expose one
> inherited from `FrameworkElement`.
>
> In order to bind the properties of the non-visual elements of the
> `XamDataGrid` such as `Field`, `FieldSettings`, or `FieldLayoutSettings`, I
> would recommend using a `FieldBinding`. You can read about `FieldBinding`
> in the `XamDataGrid` here:
> [https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-binding-field-fieldlayout-to-mvvm.](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-binding-field-fieldlayout-to-mvvm)

So, on the Infragistics site is recommended to use `FieldBinding` markup extension in order to bind properties to the `Field`, `FieldSettings`, or `FieldLayoutSettings`.
While mentioned post includes example that uses the MVVM pattern the `FieldBinding` markup extension can be used without it.

**Related to the question above consider to set the `DataContext` in the constructor:**

```cs
public YouWindowConstructor()
{        
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new DogsVM();
}
```

**Now set `DataSource` for the `XamDataGrid` and use the `FieldBinding` markup extension:**

```xml
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Path=Dogs}" AutoFit="True">
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>            
        ...
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:FieldLayout>
                <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>    
                    ...
                    <igDP:Field Name="DogName" Label="{igDP:FieldBinding ViewName}" AllowEdit="False" />   
                    ...              
                </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

See similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64545966/6630084

Answer (score 1):

So you have some object with a property named CollectionView. That object is the DataContext of the XamDataGrid. You should add a string property to *that* same object that has the value you want to use for that field's label. Then use a [FieldBinding](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.datapresenter%7Einfragistics.windows.datapresenter.fieldbinding) to bind the property of the field to that property. If that object is the DogsVM class and you just don't show CollectionView there then it would be something like `{FieldBinding ViewName}`.